# Having problem with understanding tf.where

Tags: tensorflow, migration, tensorflow2.0

I am porting tensorflow1 code to 2 and got a problem with understanding the behavior of tf.where.

Assumed tf.where(condition, x, y) basically selects x or y based on the condition.

```
tf.where([True, False, False, True], [1,2,3,4], [100,200,300,400]) # this works! - [1, 200, 300, 4]
tf.where([True, False, False, True], [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]], [[10,20],[20,30],[30,40],[40,50]]) # this raises an exception. I am expecting like [1,2], [20, 30], [30, 40], [4,5]
```

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Using tf.compat.v1.where for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tensors should be broadcastable (the dims should be either equal or 1):

```
tf.where([[True], [False], [False], [True]], [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]], [[10,20],[20,30],[30,40],[40,50]]) # this raises an exception. I am expecting like [1,2], [20, 30], [30, 40], [4,5]
```

Comment: Looks like it's a solution! Thanks, @Andrey.
One more question I have a condition = [True, False, False, True] as a tf.Variable, how do I convert it broadcastable?

Comment: this worked for me 
conditions = tf.reshape(conditions, (-1, 1))
Is that correct?

Comment: it is correct for tf.Tensor. Should be correct for tf.Variable. Didn't try though